How can I calculate the distinct number of SKUs an account has purchased over time in SQL?
I have a table that contains purchase information by account, purchase date, and the sku purchased on that day. The table is a sales order line item table, so that each record represents a separate single unity item purchase (i.e. quantity = 1 for all records).
I want to create a table on the output that will tell me, as of a particular date, what's the total number of unique skus that a given account has purchased as of that date, starting to count from the accounts first purchase date.
For example, using the data below:
create schema adhoc_data.temp;
create table adhoc_data.temp.purchases ( accountid varchar, purchase_date date, productid varchar);
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-01', '534ad451f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-02', '534ad451f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-03', '534ad451f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-04', '534ad451f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-05', '0f9d321ad');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-06', '0f9d321ad');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-07', '534ad451f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-08', '4a5d93a1f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-09', '4a5d93a1f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-10', '4a5d93a1f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-10', '534ad451f');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-10', '0f9d321ad');
insert into purchases (accountid, purchase_date, productid) values ('a1', '2022-01-11', '9cd018fc0');

I am trying to calculate:
'a1', '2022-01-01', 1
'a1', '2022-01-02', 1
'a1', '2022-01-03', 1
'a1', '2022-01-04', 1
'a1', '2022-01-05', 2
'a1', '2022-01-06', 2
'a1', '2022-01-07', 2
'a1', '2022-01-08', 3
'a1', '2022-01-09', 3
'a1', '2022-01-10', 3
'a1', '2022-01-11', 4

I have tried using an inner join on the purchases table to itself as:
select 
    t1.accountid, 
    t1.purchasedate,
    count(distinct t1.productid)
from
    purchases as t1
left join purchases as t2 on t1.accountid = t2.accountid and t1.purchase_date >= t2.purchase_date
group by 
    t1.accountid, 
    t1.purchasedate,
order by 
    t1.accountid,
    t2.purchasedate

But that's not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

count(distinct t2.productid)

Since you're always getting the same-day purchase you will always get back one row and thus don't need an outer join

I think Snowflake also let you use count(distinct productid) over (order by purchasedate)

Given the context and demo dataset you provided, the following query could be a simple approach that produce the desired output.
SELECT 
  accountid, 
  purchase_date,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p2.productid) 
    FROM purchases AS p2 
    WHERE p2.accountid = p1.accountid 
      AND p2.purchase_date <= p1.purchase_date
  ) AS unique_skus_count
FROM purchases AS p1
GROUP BY p1.accountid, p1.purchase_date
ORDER BY p1.accountid, p1.purchase_date;

Result:

Hope this helps you!

You can do this in a single scan of the base table by using window functions.

Calculate the row-number by purchase_date, partitioned for each accountid, productid
Group up by accountid, purchase_date.
The conditional count() of rows with rn = 1 are the new distinct rows per day.
A running sum over that aggregation will give you your desired result.

with byMinDate as (
    select *,
      row_number() over (partition by accountid, productid
          order by purchase_date) as rn
    from purchases
)
select
  accountid,
  purchase_date,
  sum(count(case when rn = 1 then 1 end)) over (partition by accountid order by purchase_date rows unbounded preceding) as running_distinc_count
from byMinDate
group by
  accountid,
  purchase_date;

If you instead use a filter where rn = 1 then you only get the days when there was a change in the count`
db<>fiddle

Hi Charlieface,
The sum(run=1) doesn't work with snowflake as far as I can tell, and I'm not clear on what it's doing directly? Is that basically a case statement of perform the sum of 1 when rn=1?

You can use count(case instead, yes.

Just as a follow up question: You said this can be done in a single scan, but when you're using a window function doesn't that mean on the back end of the database engine it's still doing multiple passes through the data in order to sort it first, or is it able to optimize the compute path better using a window function?

Different DBMSs have different ways of doing this, but I know SQL Server can do it in a single pass. If you use OVER without an ORDER BY then it does cache some of the data in memory while calculating the entire partition, but it's still much more efficient than multiple passes.

Thanks, that's interesting and good to know. I appreciate your insights.
